# Hive doesn't show tables when started from another directory

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive, cloudera, rhel

I installed Hive cdh4 on RHEL. Whenever I start Hive from a directory, it creates metastore_db dir in it and a derby.log file. Is it a normal behaviour? Moreover, when I create a table, starting Hive from a particular directory; I'm unable to see that table when I start Hive from a directory, other than that.

For example,
Let's say I started Hive from my home dir, i.e. $HOME or ~ and I create table in Hive. But when I start Hive from /path/to/my/Hive/directory and do a show tables, the table i just creted wouldn't show up. However, if  start Hive from my home directory again and look for tables, I'm able to see the table.

Also, if I make some changes in hive-site.xml, they are simply being ignored by Hive.

Please help me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this and use one metastore_db by updating "$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-default.xml" file's "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" as below:

```
    <property>
       <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
       <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/path/to/my/metastore_db;create=true</value>
       <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>
```

Where `/path/to/my/metastore_db` is the location you want to keep your meta store dB.

Comment: hi @scarle88 ! Thanks for your help. But if I make some changes in hive-site.xml, they are simply being ignored by Hive. In the new Hive, they have hive-default.xml.tempelate in $HIVE_HOME/conf while the hive-site.xml is in $HIVE_HOME/src/conf/hive-site.xml or $HIVE_HOME/src/common/src/test/resources/hive-site.xml. So, now which one do I change ?

Comment: By default there is no hive-site.xml in the $HIVE_HOME/conf/ folder. The hive-default.xml is simply full of example settings you can overwrite in hive. In order to override settings you simple need to create a hive-site.xml file in $HIVE_HOME/conf/ and add the megastore.dB settings above and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @scarle88. I have one more question, it might sound stupid, but is there a way to set a default dir where derby.log can be created and not just anywhere ?

Comment: I changed my answer above to be a bit clearer. Yes, the path you specify in the connectionURL /path/to/my/metastore_db is where hive keeps the derby stuff, including the derby.log.

Comment: @Harman:  I have done the same. However, derby.log is getting created in the directory from which I am starting hive. I am using hive 0.11.0. Please find the configuration in my hive-site.xml.  <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/srinivas/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

Comment: @Srinivas are you still stuck with it ?

Comment: @Harman: with the absolute path, my metastore_db is ok now. However, derby.log is getting created in the directory from which I am starting hive. Could you help me?

Comment: @MichaelD.this is how Derby is configured. If log file generation in the directory poses a challenge to your environment, you should move to an external database as metastore, which will give you more control.

Comment: @MichaelD.hope [this](http://davidvancouvering.blogspot.in/2007/10/quiet-time-and-how-to-suppress-derbylog.html) helps you with a better picture.